# Make javagent use system classloader in Java < 9

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, classloader, jvm-arguments

I have a java-agent which relies on some dependency libraries. We have a custom classloader which does not do globbing and provides deterministic class loading, and is specified via the `-Djava.system.class.loader=`. However it seems that the java-agent classes are still getting loaded via the AppClassLoader, leading to some `ClassNotFoundException`s. After having wasted a couple of hours on this, I came across this [JDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8160950) which outlines this exact issue and is closed now, but the fix has been made only to JDK 9+.

I was wondering is there a way in Java <=8 to enforce the java-agent classes to be loaded by the classloader specified.

The custom class loader looks something like this,

```
public class CustomClassloader extends URLClassLoader{ 

    public CustomClassloader(ClassLoader parent) throws Exception {
         //getJarPaths has the path of the java-agent jar as well as
         //all dependency jar it needs.
        super(getJarPaths(), parent);
    }


    private static URL[] getJarPaths() throws Exception {
       //custom implementation
    }


    public void appendToClassPathForInstrumentation(String path) throws   MalformedURLException {
        assert(Thread.holdsLock(this));
        super.addURL(Paths.get(path).toUri().toURL());
    }
}
```

The above classloader works perfectly with JDK9+, and the javaagent is actually loaded by the custom classloader.

Comment: Did you spell `java.system.class.loader` correctly? Does your ClassLoader specify `null` as a parent ClassLoader? Can't reproduce the problem. My JDK 8u221 successfully loads agent class and its dependencies using custom system ClassLoader. Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes the `java.system.class.loader` is correctly specified, updated the question. I can't make the parent classloader as null, as extension classpath (containing e.g. JCE classes) seems to be included in the parent classloader.

Comment: If your custom ClassLoader delegates to the parent ClassLoader (which is system class loader) before attempting to find the class itself, the agent will be loaded by the system class loader. That's basically how class loading works, it's not a bug. The problem is not clear. Please, provide an example.

Comment: Updated question with Custom classloader. What I am not understanding is why this works perfectly with JDK9+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between JDK 8 and JDK 9+ is that JDK 8 adds `-javaagent` jar to the system class path, while JDK 9+ calls `appendToClassPathForInstrumentation` of the custom ClassLoader instead.

So, in JDK 8, if your custom ClassLoader delegates to the parent ClassLoader (which is system class loader) before attempting to find the class itself, the agent will be loaded by the system class loader. In order to workaround this, your custom ClassLoader may reverse delegation order: first try to find a class itself, then delegate to the parent.

For example, this can be done by overriding `loadClass` method as shown below:

```
@Override
protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    synchronized (getClassLoadingLock(name)) {
        Class<?> c = findLoadedClass(name);
        if (c == null) {
            try {
                c = findClass(name);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                c = super.loadClass(name, false);
            }
        }
        if (resolve) {
            resolveClass(c);
        }
        return c;
    }
}

@Override
public URL getResource(String name) {
    URL url = findResource(name);
    if (url != null) {
        return url;
    }
    return super.getResource(name);
}

@Override
public Enumeration<URL> getResources(String name) throws IOException {
    List<URL> urls = Collections.list(findResources(name));
    urls.addAll(Collections.list(getParent().getResources(name)));
    return Collections.enumeration(urls);
}
```

Comment: Updated my question to indicate I am extending the URLClassloader. Does this solution still work?

Comment: @AdwaitKumar It does. I tested it exactly against URLClassLoader.

Comment: This sort of works, but for some reason a dependency class which is present in another jar is not dynamically loaded, and I am ending with a NoClassDefFound error. I put in logging statements to print out class names for which the overriden `loadClass` is called but the dependency class is not being logged. I also logged the jar paths and can see the dependency jar present. Also doing a `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("dependencyClass)` in premain of javaagent is able to load the class.

Comment: @AdwaitKumar A similar trick with reversion may be also required for `getResource`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Try `-XX:+TraceClassLoding -XX:+TraceClassResolution` to see what happens.

Comment: Tried with your updated code, doesn't seem to be working. I can't see the dependency class anywhere with `-XX:+TraceClassLoding -XX:+TraceClassResolution`, unless I do an explicit load.  Will probably create a github repo to share MVE